# INSERT query doesn't return an object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm simply trying to retrieve the inserted row's unique ID. Why doesn't this code work?

```
include('lib_connection.php');
$con = dbconnect();
$res = $con->query("insert into schools(school,city) values('CyFair High School','houston') ");
echo $res->insert_id;
$con->close();
```

I only get:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\wampserver\www\hwsource\do_test.php on line 5
```

dbconnect() works fine. The query also executes fine and inserts the values in the DB, but I don't get an object returned. I simply get a boolean true. If Insert doesn't return an object, then how can I retrieve the inserted ID?

Comment: what is the code of dbconnect?

Comment: non-object implies that the insert failed and returned a boolean false. try `$con->error` (or whatever your db lib's error interface is). Of course, this assumes that line 5 is the echo line. if it's on the `$res = $con...` then you've failed to connect to the db at all.

Comment: what does `var_dump($res);` show?

Comment: The error is here `$con->close();`.

Comment: Please post the code of the `dbconnect` class/method/whatever. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: Are you sure that you connected to a specific database?  Because the query only has the table name.

Comment: @MarcB no it doesn't! mysql_db_query returns a resultobject if he does a select and TRUE/FALSE if he does an update!

Comment: dbconnect() works. It's simply new mysqli("host","user","pass","database");

Comment: I edited the question and added the returned variable type. It's a true boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");  //use your data
$mysqli->query("insert into schools(school,city) values('CyFair High School','houston') ");
echo $mysqli->insert_id
$mysqli->close();
```

**UPDATED:**
instead of $con->close() try mysql_close($con);

Comment: My code: mysqli->insert_id, Your code: mysql->insert_id. I think, mysql->insert_id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right to asume that your dbconnection uses the plain and simple mysql functions then just replace

```
echo $res->insert_id;
```

with:

```
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: i'm using object-oriented mysqli format. This still gave me the same error.

Comment: I edited the question and added the returned variable type. It's a true boolean, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO you need to set the fetch mode to PDO::FETCH_OBJECT...Also if your code is returning an array you can simply cast it to object like this (object) $res.

Comment: I edited the question and added the returned variable type. It's a true boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Amend

`echo $res->insert_id;`

to

`echo $con->insert_id;`

It's an old question at this stage, but the best answers remain ambiguous, so I thought I'd clarify, using the actual variable names in the question, and the usual currently implemented PHP versions.

My answer works if `$con` is a `mysqli` object, which it probably is (and not the older `mysql` -- the 'i' stands for 'improved'). Thus, when performing its query method it

> returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.[[Source]](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

This explains the error message, as the query is an `INSERT`.

I came here as a result of a textbook instructing me to get the insert_id from the result and not the mysqli object itself, but I can't find any justification for this in the documentation for past or present versions of MySQL.